# PHP errors, select values, radio buttons

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a contact form on my website, however I have very little PHP experience. I was able to get the email sending but there are errors. I cannot select an email from the dropdown to send to, The file attachment isn't functioning, the fields are showing up like this in my email- Name: . except for the "firstname field" that shows up First Name : "Correct Name"... any help or direction would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form name="secure" class="form-secure" action="contact.php" 
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <h4 class="secure-header pb-2 text-dark">Secure Email Form</h4>
    <p class="text-secondary let-p font-italic">Please fill out 
        the form below to send your representative or department a 
        secure email</p>
    <form class="form secure-email-form">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-row">    
                <p><select name="recipient" id="recipient">
                    <option value="" class="form-control">Select Recipient *
                    </option>
                    <option 
      value="implementations@masspay.net">Implementation</option> . 
      <option 
      value="operations@masspay.net">Operations</option><option 
      value="tax@masspay.net">Tax</option><option 
      value="training@masspay.net">Training</option><option 
      value="sales@masspay.net">Sales</option><option 
      value="josh@masspay.net">Josh Soroko</option><option 
      value="jason@masspay.net">Jason Maxwell</option><option 
      value="jcarini@masspay.net">Jacklyn Carini</option><option 
      value="katie@masspay.net">Katie Rogers</option><option 
      value="jpowers@masspay.net">Jourdan Powers</option><option 
      value="brogers@masspay.net">Brittany Rogers</option><option 
      value="cflint@masspay.net">Charmaine Flint</option><option 
      value="knegron@masspay.net">Karina Negron</option><option 
      value="afox@masspay.net">Andrew Fox</option><option 
      value="paula@masspay.net">Paula Papalambros</option><option 
      value="mmcloy@masspay.net">Missy McLoy</option></select>

                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="subject" id="subject" class="form- 
 control" type="text" placeholder="Subject *"></p>              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group second-row">
            <p><label><span class="attachment">Attachment </span>      
                <input name="fileMain"  class="form-control" id="fileMain" 
   type="file"></label></p>

        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="firstname" id="firstname"  
     class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name *"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="lastname" id="lastname"  
    class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name *"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="email" type="text"  class="form- 
       control" id="email" placeholder="Email *"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="emailC" type="text"  class="form- 
     control" id="emailC" placeholder="Confirm Email *"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="form-field organization">
                <input type="text" value="" class="text email- 
    org form-control" size="56" maxlength="255" onchange="" . 
      placeholder="Organization"> 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><input name="phone"  class="form-control" type="tel" value="" placeholder="Phone"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p>
                  <select name="stateSelect" id="state"  class="form-control">

                    <option value="">Select Your State *</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control form-field mb-3" type="textarea" name="message"  id="how-can-we-help-you" placeholder="How Can We Help You?" cols="55"  rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="prefered-contact">
                      <p>Prefered method of contact: <br>
                        <label class="mr-2">
                          <input name="contactmethod" id="contactmethod"  class="form-control" type="radio" value="Phone"> Phone
                        </label>
                        <label>
                                      <input name="contactmethod"  class="form-control" id="contactmethod" type="radio" value="Email" checked="checked"> Email
                        </label>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="form-field %%form-field-css-classes%% pd-captcha required hidden   %%form-field-dependency-css%%">


                      </p>


                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcw2H0UAAAAAPtObq6EBHb0JfBDaQcXcA1Esr-8"></div>            

                    <p></p>
                    <div id="error_for_Recaptchapi_Recaptcha" style="display:none"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">


                        <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="☃">

                        <p class="submit submit-email">
                          <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Submit" class="submit-form">
                        </p>

                </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenDependentFields" id="hiddenDependentFields" value="">
            </form>
        </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$fileMain = $_POST['fileMain'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailC = $_POST['emailC'];
$organization = $_POST['organization'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$email_from = 'MP Secure Email';
$email_subject = 'New Message From MP Secure Email';
$email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
              "Subject: $name.\n".
              "File: $fileMain.\n".
              "First Name: $firstname.\n".
              "Last Name: $lasttname.\n".
              "Email: $email.\n".
              "Email Confirm: $emailC.\n".
              "Organization: $organization.\n".
              "Phone: $phone.\n".
              "Message: $message.\n";

$to ="mdonatelli@masspay.net";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("location: index.html");


if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['recipient'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit-form']) )
    {
      $varGender = $_POST['stateSelect'];
      $errorMessage = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['radio']))
        {
            echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: $to =$_POST['recipient'];   change that line so that it would consider the dropdown value.

Comment: You should try and keep your question 1:1, so 1 issue per question. You've just listed a bunch of issues. **Edit:** Why do you have nested `<form>` tags?